# Sql query for multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

My scenario,
I have table "datatable" which contains many fields, out of this i need two field for my  condition, the field described below

```
Record  scenes    Field1    Feild2
 r1     Scene a    1       0
 r2     Scene b    0       1
 r3     Scene c    1       1
 r4     Scene d    0       0
 .        .        1       0
 .        .        0       0
          .        1       1
 r n     Scene n    1       0
```

here "1" represents column has data and "0 represents null

In my case four different ways data inserted, I want to fetch all the values which contains 1 i.e. data and ignore null values without loss data .
how to write query?

for e.g.:

```
select * from datatable
where (field1!=0 and field2=0)
or (field1=0 and field2!=0)
or (field1!=0 and field2!=0)
or field1=0 and field2=0
```

desired output:
Scene a(r1),
Scene b(r2),
Scene C(r3),
scene d+1(r+1),
scene (n-1)(r-1)

here r represents records.

if i go with select * from datatable
    where field1 is not null and field2 is not null;

then the output will be
scene c and scene (n-1)..this is the problem .

Scene represents records
unfortunately I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: What is your desired result set ?

Comment: Peraphs you want SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE field1 != 0 or field2 != 0. So you have 3 rows (Scene D has discarded)

Comment: can you explain clearly :-" I want fetch the all values which contains 1" SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE field1 != 0 AND field2 != 0... do u want tis

Comment: yes! I want scene a,b,c as output, this is the case of 4 records in 4 scenarios..there are 100 of records in the table , stored data in above 4 scenario fashion, fetch all the  records

Comment: It's columns, not fields...

Comment: "where field1 is not null and field2 is not null"

Comment: that wont work, because, it will work when field1 is 1 and field2 is 1 this case is only true.(using and operator thats why ) rest of the data not fetched

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice 0 meant NULL, I thought it was value 0... But, as already asked for, what's the desired result when havingt the input data as already specified?

Comment: i have mentioned the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use "or" in place of "and" operator. Try the below query:

SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE field1! ='0' or field2!= '0'